# Change the template of my Blog entries

Tags: customization, blog, header-image

My blog entries always display as background of the title an image that I'd like to eliminate.

I'd like to have only the title and below the image selected by me in every entry. How could I eliminate that image and leave only the title?
Moreover I don't know why the image selected by me has a link that redirect the user to the image itself. Take a look to my last entry:

https://www.editorialufv.es/presentacion-del-libro-geriatria/

Which file manage the structure of the single-post entries?

The template I've bought use Kodeforest in order to customize the blog entries but it seems that what I'm looking for (so easy and so obvious) is something that Kodeforest doesn't let users to do. Take a look to the Kodeforest instructions for blog custom:

http://www.kodeforest.net/wp-demo/petcare/doc/

Answer (score 0):

For most WordPress based sides, you can look at the classes on the `body` tag to find out what kind of content is being shown, a single post, a post archive, the front page etc. In your case, it's `post-template-default single single-post postid-2897 single-format-standard wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-5.0.1 vc_responsive`, so this is a single post that is shown (most of those classes come out of [get_body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/), it's worth a look at the code to fully understand how that works).

To find the file responsible, look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and check your theme which files exist.

If you change your original theme directly, you'll lose those changes when you update to a newer version. Instead, create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to adapt the original theme to your needs. This allows you to override certain files but keep the rest as it is.